# System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions.set_AllowAreas(Boolean)'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I get the following error message when I run a brand new web application:

System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.RazorPagesOptions.set_AllowAreas(Boolean)'.'

I'm guessing I need to download a nuget package, but can't work out which one?

My startup.cs code is below - the failure is on endpoints.MapRazor();

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            //services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
            {
                options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";         // Microsoft identity platform

                options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false; // accept several tenants (here simplified)
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureADAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c.<AddAdditionalMvcApplicationParts>b__6_0(RazorPagesOptions o)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`1.Configure(String name, TOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsManager`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.CompiledPageRouteModelProvider..ctor(ApplicationPartManager applicationManager, IOptions`1 pagesOptionsAccessor, ILogger`1 logger)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitIEnumerable(IEnumerableCallSite enumerableCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitNoCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RazorPagesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.EnsureRazorPagesServices(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RazorPagesEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapRazorPages(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Web.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__5_0(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints) in C:\\Users\\Liam\\Source\\Repos\\TradingReplay\\Web\\Startup.cs:line 83
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) in C:\\Users\\Liam\\Source\\Repos\\TradingReplay\\Web\\Startup.cs:line 81
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<UseStartup>b__2(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISServerSetupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.GenericWebHostService.<StartAsync>d__31.MoveNext()
```

Comment: What happens if you uncomment `//services.AddRazorPages();` ?

Comment: I've tried that - the same thing happens

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 3.0?

Comment: Yes - though I had deleted this one and recreated it, but its still v3

Comment: That's really important to know to get a good answer. There have been a lot of changes in 3.0. I added the `asp.net-core-3.0` tag to your question.

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Thanks. That shows that it's `MapRazorPages()` throwing the exception. Have you tried removing `.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)`?

Comment: It doesn't make any difference - I've tried that too. Interestingly I can't even see AllowAreas as a property in the RazorOptions class, which is why I suspect I'm missing a library.

Comment: What is your .net core sdk version? Share us detail steps to reproduce your issue. I made a test with asp.net core with AAD authentication under .net core sdk prview6, it works correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because incompatible versions of some libraries like Identity, Go to Nuget Manager and update packages to the latest preview versions.

Answer (score 13):

In an ASP.NET Core 3.0 App the Nuget Package "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI" (and dependencies) must be updated to v3.0.0 (or newer) in order to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

Updating to the latest versions just created more 'incompatibility issues' for me. This it totally crap by Microsoft.
Updating to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI version 3.1.0 worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this exact runtime error. It was because I still had a .NET Core 2.2 project in my solution ([Microsoft.Identity.Web](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/Microsoft.Identity.Web)). I unloaded that project, rebuilt my solution, and that solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because I had pasted a project reference into my `.csproj` field with out a Version. When I added the version that is compatible with my other packages, it resolved the issue. The package I had an issue with was Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="6.0.0" />
```